# Search terms containing period, ".", does not yield any results.

Tags: external-content-type, enterprise-search

Using external content types, I am trying to create an asset management system for administering, among other things, IP addresses. Using an enterprise search center, the crawler indexes the external content just fine, but when searching for an IP address, no results are returned.

I.e., if the entire scope for 192.168.1.0/24 is documented, searching for "192.168.1.35" yields no results. Searching for just "192" or "168" returns all the addresses, but when searching for "192." or "168.", that is, with a punctuation mark, nothing is returned.

Have I done something wrong? Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint sees the period as a word breaker (which means it treats each section of the IP Address as a separate word in the index and does not put them together).  The only way to modify how SharePoint treats word breakers is with a custom dictionary: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263242.aspx

Comment: So essentially I will need to create a custom dictionary containing any and all IP addresses that could be created in the system, one IP per line in the file?

Comment: That appears to be the case, yes.  I haven't seen a way to use wildcards or regex in the Custom Dictionaries.